# "Vor rund eineinhalb Jahr, seitdem habe ich dich kennengelernt, warst du eine andere Person" is correct?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-case, word-order

Grammatically, the sentence above is correct? I have hesitations for e.g. "vor rund eineinhalb Jahr" or "vor rund eineinhalbem Jahr", and whether "seitdem" is in the right position?

Comment: One and a half is plural in German, just like in English.

Answer (score 4):

The sentence is semantically wrong.

Let's split it up:

> Vor rund eineinhalb Jahren warst du eine andere Person.

This is a point in time. You cannot insert something with *seitdem* as this word describe a range of time, or more precisely since a time in the past until now. But you can use, for instance, *als* becaus this word denotes again a specific point in time.

> Vor rund eineinhalb Jahren, als ich dich kennengelernt habe, warst du eine andere Person.

If you want to use *seitdem*, you first must make up a time range:

> In den letzten eineinhalb Jahren hast du dich verändert.

Here you refer with "In den letzten Jahren" to a range of time and then again you can insert something with *seitdem*.

> In den letzten eineinhalb Jahren, seitdem ich dich kennengelernt habe, hast du dich verändert.

Comment: I emphasized an alternative version of the original translation: *Vor rund eineinhalb Jahren – seitdem habe ich dich kennengelernt – warst du eine andere Person.* This is surely not what Khaled wanted to say, but I still see no semantical problem for the alternate meaning.

Comment: @lejonet True. But to grasp the idea is quite a challenge for non-natives. You certainly should say more on this, if you like to pick this up in your answer.

Comment: I tried to clarify it.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you want to say that somebody changed in the last one and a half year of your relationship? Choose this translation:

> Als ich dich vor eineinhalb/anderthalb Jahren kennenlernte, warst du eine andere Person.

*Person* works here, but *Mensch* is more common:

> Als ich dich vor eineinhalb/anderthalb Jahren kennenlernte, warst du ein anderer *Mensch*.

Your translation

> Vor rund eineinhalb Jahr, seitdem habe ich dich kennengelernt, warst du eine andere Person.

is almost correct (*Jahren* instead of *Jahr*), **but** it describes a setting you most likely do not mean:

- Someone already was a different person than you thought one and a half year ago.
- You know that *now*, because you got to know this person better.

(You could also write it like this then: *Vor rund eineinhalb Jahren – seitdem habe ich dich kennengelernt – warst du eine andere Person (für mich).*) This sentence might work e.g. in a mystery story.